# Jquery Datepicker - Enabled dates from mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datepicker

In my application I want to show a datepicker (jquery) where only some dates are enabled. I get those dates from MySql DB. How can I send these paramemeters to datepicker through ajax?

```
<input type="text" name="t_Date" id="t_Date">
<script>
    $("#t_Date").datepicker({ 
       datesEnabled : ajax_getDates.php // Here what I need help 
    });
</script>
```

I don't know whether the `getDates` methode exists or not.

Comment: Where is your code? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="t_Date" id="t_Date">
<script>$("#t_Date").datepicker({
      datesEnabled : ajax_getDates.php // Here what I need help 
})</script>`. Dont know whether the `getDates` methode exists or not.

Comment: Please add your code, what have tried yet

Comment: please add your code in description instead of comment so that it is easy to read and so that it is useful to everyone.

Comment: Ok. I will paste the code to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an ajax request and create the date picker on success callback:

```
<input type="text" name="t_Date" id="t_Date">
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.post('ajax_getDates.php', {}, function(data){
            $("#t_Date").datepicker({ datesEnabled : data.datesEnabled });
        }, 'json');

    });

</script>
```

The `ajax_getDates.php` file should look like:

```
<?php

    $datesEnabled = array('date1', 'date2', 'date3');
    echo json_encode('datesEnabled' => $datesEnabled);
```

Comment: Thank you. Other than `document.ready function1, can I call 1datesEnabled : data.datesEnabled` on other events? like button `onClick`?

Comment: you can do it inside the callback.. you can do whatever you like with that variable

Comment: Oh yes... I got now. Thanks a lot.